# NestJs error: can't resolve dependencies of the Service (?). Please make sure that the argument SchemaModel at index [0] is available

Tags: nestjs, nest

I get this error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserPreferencesService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserPreferencesSchemaModel at index [0] is available in the UserPreferencesModule context.
```

What can the error be? I understand that the problem happens in the `user-preferences.service.ts` file. as when I comment the following lines from the `user-preferences.module.ts` file all works fine.

```
  controllers: [UserPreferencesController],
  providers: [UserPreferencesService],
```

This is my `user-preferences.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserPreferencesInterface } from './interfaces/user-preferences.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UserPreferencesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('UserPreferencesSchema')
    private readonly UserPreferencesModel: Model<UserPreferencesInterface>,
  ) {}

  public async postUserPreferences(newUserPreferences: any): Promise<any> {
    const userPreferences = await new this.UserPreferencesModel(
      newUserPreferences,
    );
    return userPreferences.save();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { UserPreferencesModule } from './user-preferences/user-preferences.module';
    import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        UserPreferencesModule,
        MongooseModule.forRoot(
          'mongodb+srv://user:pass@db.hucjifz.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        ),
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

`user-preferences.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserPreferencesSchema } from './schemas/user-preferences.schema';
import { UserPreferencesController } from './user-preferences.controller';
import { UserPreferencesService } from './user-preferences.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'UserPreferences',
        schema: UserPreferencesSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserPreferencesController],
  providers: [UserPreferencesService],
})
export class UserPreferencesModule {}
```

user-preferences.controller.ts

```
import {Body, Controller, Get, Post, Put } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserPreferencesService } from './user-preferences.service';
import { UserPreferencesDto }  from './dto/user-preferences.dto'
@Controller('user-preferences')
export class UserPreferencesController {
    
    
    constructor(private userPreferencesService: UserPreferencesService) {}

    @Get()
    public getUserPreferences() {
        return this.userPreferencesService.getUserPreferences();
    }

    @Post ()
    public postUserPreferences(
        @Body() userPreferences: UserPreferencesDto
    ) {
        return this.userPreferencesService.postUserPreferences( userPreferences );
    }

}
```

this is the complete error:

```
[Nest] 65481  - 06/07/2022, 6:00:04 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserPreferencesService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserPreferencesSchemaModel at index [0] is available in the UserPreferencesModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UserPreferencesSchemaModel is a provider, is it part of the current UserPreferencesModule?
- If UserPreferencesSchemaModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserPreferencesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserPreferencesSchemaModel */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserPreferencesService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserPreferencesSchemaModel at index [0] is available in the UserPreferencesModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UserPreferencesSchemaModel is a provider, is it part of the current UserPreferencesModule?
- If UserPreferencesSchemaModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserPreferencesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserPreferencesSchemaModel */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:231:19)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:184:33)
    at resolveParam (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:106:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:121:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:52:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:74:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:44:9)
    at /Users/davids/Developmet/nestjs/sync-user-preferences/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:29:13
```

Comment: The issue seems to pertain to the UserPreferencesSchemaModel and the way it's used in the UserPreferenceModule. Could you post your user-preferences.controller.js

Comment: Thanks for your attention!! I added the file content to the answer.

Comment: the problem is in the `MongooseModule.forFeature` name, for some reason I don't fully understand it can't receive any name.

Answer (score 0):

O.K, after digging alot I found that the problem was caused because `MongooseModule.forFeature` `name` and `@InjectModel()` in `user-preferences.service.ts` value were not identical.

**They must be identical**.